# Getting an error in creating a GoogleApiClient

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

When i am trying to create a google API client I got an error on the second line

***.addApi(LocationServices.API)***

```
  GoogleApiClient  mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
```

how can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Please paste your `Logcat` Error

Comment: LocationServices is not appear when i am writing the code.

Comment: i can't getting you